# How to post fieldmap array in retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I really don't if my question exactly but I'm just asking on how to post the array in retrofit using `FormUrlEncoded`?

this is what I'm doing in PostMan's parameter.

[image]

Now I want to do that in retrofit and I'm using a `FieldMap`.
 (I really don't have an idea on how to do this)
This is what I did. (It's not working)

```
private var properties: HashMap<String, String>

for (i in myStringCollection) {
    properties["properties[option1]"] = "1" + i
    properties["properties[option2]"] = "1"
    properties["properties[option3]"] = "1"
    properties["properties[option4]"] = "No option"
}

registerUser(properties)
```

and this is my api

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers(PUBLIC_API_KEY)
@POST("www/register/register/")
fun registerUser(
    @FieldMap properties: Map<String, String>
): Observable<DefaultResponse>
```

any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: refer this link https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=retrofit.http.FieldMap